# Why can I ssh to my server but cannot sftp into it?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sftp

I've got a VPS running Ubuntu 9.10 and I cannot sftp to the server with a regular account. I can ssh with a regular account and I can also ssh and sftp with root.
Is there an option that I need to turn on so that regular users can use sftp?
Thanks in advance,
J.

Comment: Post your `sshd_config` and the relevant entries from your logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem was caused by wrong permissions set for /dev/null: crw-------. Now i only have to figure out why the permissions where set the way they were :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's because of permissions on 'sftp-server' binary? what does debug run of sshd give you?

Answer (score 0):

Another issue that I have noticed, is that if your login startup files generate any sort of output, scp and sftp fail.  Be sure you bracket things that output to the terminal in your startup scripting using a test on the variable $?prompt if it is non-zero you talking with a terminal.